# How to change the existing cluster and instance admin username which is controlled by terraform?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

Currently I have an existing Aurora PostgreSQL cluster running in Serverless v2 mode created by terraform.

```
    # AWS Aurora Cluster
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_cluster" {
  tags                            = var.tags
  cluster_identifier              = "my-db-${var.environment}"
  engine                          = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_mode                     = "provisioned"
  engine_version                  = var.engine_version
  db_subnet_group_name            = aws_db_subnet_group.subnet_group.name
  database_name                   = "my-db"
  manage_master_user_password     = true
  master_username                 = "postgres"
  port                            = 5432
  storage_encrypted               = true
  vpc_security_group_ids          = [aws_security_group.allow_db_connection.id]
  apply_immediately               = true
  skip_final_snapshot             = true
  availability_zones              = var.availability_zones
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = [
    "postgresql"
  ]
  backup_retention_period = "7"

  serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
    max_capacity = 10.0
    min_capacity = 1.0
  }
}


# AWS Aurora Instance
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_instance" {
  tags                 = var.tags
  cluster_identifier   = "my-db-${var.environment}"
  identifier           = "my-db-${var.environment}"
  instance_class       = var.instance_class
  availability_zone    = var.availability_zone
  engine               = aws_rds_cluster.aurora_cluster.engine
  engine_version       = aws_rds_cluster.aurora_cluster.engine_version
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.subnet_group.name
}
```

AWS security hub is showing me following issues for it:
RDS Database Clusters should use a custom administrator username
RDS database instances should use a custom administrator username

I want to change it from "postgres" to custom name for cluster and instance. What should be the steps for it? I dont think we can simply modify the value of existing cluster. Should i create the new one ? take the snapshot of the exiting cluster and restore it ? but then restored snapshot will be new DB cluster i think.

Can someone help me with the process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to AWS documentation you can't:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html

Comment: and i if create a new cluster then how can i restore the data from old cluster to new one ?

Comment: You can check AWS DMS to migrate data